# How to update column if another column fulfill specific criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb

I need to update one column if another column has a specific data.

Usually if I want to update one column, I do the following SQL Query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = replace(field1, 'oldstring', 'newstring')
```

But what I can't figure is how to make it look up one column, and if that field has some data, it should update another column's field.

Here is what I want to do.

1. look in table: **phpbb_tree**
2. under column: **spouses_total**
3. if the field is empty (has no data)
4. update column: **page_template**
5. update from: **tree_body_spouse_1.html** to: **tree_body_single.html**

So basically, I know how to do the "update" part, but don't know how to make it look first in one column, and if empty (or matches) it should do the following:

```
UPDATE phpbb_tree
SET page_template = replace(page_template, 'tree_body_spouse_1.html', 'tree_body_single.html')
```

Hopefully someone could tell me how to write it up.  I don't even know if it's even possible to do a search for an empty data in a column?

Comment: Um, just apply `where` criteria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CASE expression to fulfill different condition of replacement.

```
UPDATE phpbb_tree
SET  page_template = (CASE  
                        WHEN spouses_total is null  
                          THEN replace(page_template, 'tree_body_spouse_1.html', 'tree_body_single.html')            
                        ELSE page_template
                        END 
                       );
```

**Edit:**

Please check this..

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/519806)</kbd>

Comment: I tested your recommendation.  But It didn't work.  I got the following message when I ran it:  0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0023 sec)

Comment: How about we first convert the empty data in spouses_total from "empty" to "0" , perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: @Jay-Jay I have provided SQL fiddle to show that it's works fine, look at 2 rows, one which has null value modified accordingly, other one's not.

Comment: I was able to convert the empty data in spouses_total to a 0.  Now can you rewrite the above query so I can see if this works now?

Comment: @Jay-Jay just change WHEN spouses_total = 0 in CASE expression.Result will be same.

Comment: Check this...http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/519799

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake earlier.  both templates had .html extensions, where before, I had goofed up and wrote one with .htm.  too bad I didn't spot it at first.  I'm sure it would have worked the way you provided it early on, but now since I converted all the empty rows for that column to 0 -- I need a new modified version.

Comment: Thanks!  It works now. I would've wish to try it when it was "null" data in those rows, for me to check your previous solution.  But now that you provided me this additional info, I can now continue working with my table.  I really appreciate the tip.  Now I can always use this when I find myself in the same situation. :)  - Consider this SOLVED.

Comment: @Jay-Jay I am glad to help you, here's the final link http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/519803